# How to pass in parameter into saga?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

In my react component I have:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

function postOne(props, p) {
  debugger
  props.onRequestGet(p);
}

function App(props) {
  const { datas } = props;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {datas}
      <button onClick={()=>postOne(props,1)}>post 1</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    datas: state
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onRequestGet: p => dispatch({ type: "API_GET_REQUEST", data: p })
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

I am trying to pass the parameter p into the actionrequest. The saga code looks like this:

```
import { takeLatest, call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import axios from "axios";

// how to pass in parameter here?
export function* watcherSaga(p) {
  yield takeLatest("API_GET_REQUEST", workerSaga,p);

}

// worker saga: makes the api call when watcher saga sees the action
function* workerSaga() {
  try {
    debugger
    const response = yield call(fetchGet);
    const post = response.data.author;

    // dispatch a success action to the store with the new dog
    yield put({ type: "API_GET_SUCCESS", post });
  } catch (error) {
    // dispatch a failure action to the store with the error
    yield put({ type: "API_CALL_FAILURE", error });
  }
}


// how to pass in parameter p?
function fetchGet(p) {
  debugger
  return axios({
    method: "get",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/posts/"+p
  });
}
```

I tried to pass in the parameter ie action payload in the watcherSaga function but no result. How can I pass in the parameter?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/dimitri-a/saga_stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass parameters in `call()`

```
const response = yield call(fetchGet, p)
```

https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callfn-args